# Can we implement Row Lost Focus event for GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a Hierarchical gridview and I need implement the following functionality in the child gridview:

1. Show all the rows in editable mode (this can be done)
2. Save all data of each row on it's lost focus

We can capture the mouse events but how do we track the row lost focus triggered by the Keyboard. Ex: when a row is in focus, hitting f6 will go directly to browser address bar which results in the row lost focus event.

One mouse move across the rows will trigger all the validation and save logic for all the rows, this screen has hierarchical control and the child gridview has a minimum of 200 rows.

Any thoughts on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to implement a postback / callback when the blur event fires for the row on the client-side. I'm not exactly sure which DOM elements support the blur event in every browser but you can do it.

The GridEX control from Janus Systems can do it, but honestly, I'd really stay clear of doing things like Janus Systems do, so it's better you should find your own way.

**EDIT:** Try [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut29.htm).

Comment: How should I track the Keyboard events ??

Comment: Added a link. It's very basic, but you can move on from there.